# Programmatically get Windows Setting | Account Setting | Require Sign In

Tags: c++, api, winapi, wmi

I have an issue when tried to get Windows Setting programmatically. I want to detect if user have config Require Sign-In when PC wake up from sleep or not. I can get information from Screen Saver Setting only, but it's not sufficient in this case.
I googling a lot but can not find any solution, Is it possible?
Thanks
[Screen Capture Require Sign In option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ0sU.png)

Comment: Would you specify which setting? A screenshot might help. It might be plausibly stored in registry and you can set it through C++.

Comment: I did try to get it from Registry Table, but can only read Screen Saver Setting.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/how-to-disable-the-lock-screen/d1d0f154-085b-4c4e-b04f-98f14ca60656

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually, I just want to know is it a programmatically way to detect that if PC User have config "Require Sign-In" option to "When PC wakes up from sleep". Maybe like this: CallNtPowerInformation().SignInOption == Windows.AfterSleep !
The solution you provided can not detect that option also. And I don't want to change any value in Registry Table, just query value.

Comment: Use `WM_POWERBROADCAST ` to detect operation is resuming automatically from a low-power state. If you receive `PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC` and the screen saver does not appear on the computer， then Require Sign-In is Never Option.

Comment: Thanks Strive Sun for your reply and your useful solution.
But our situation is that, every 15 minutes our software will query System Information and send the report to cloud and according to your solution, if the PC did't go to sleep state / wakes up, we can not receive the message and detect Sign-In option. Is it another way to detect the option right after start the software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after a long search, I found the answer you need, with the help of `PowerGetActiveScheme ()` and `PowerReadDCValueIndex ()`

Code Sample: (C#)

According to your needs, you can easily convert to C ++.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PowrprofTest
{
    class Program
    {

        private static readonly Guid CONSOLELOCK = new Guid("0e796bdb-100d-47d6-a2d5-f7d2daa51f51");
        private static readonly Guid SUB_NONE = new Guid("fea3413e-7e05-4911-9a71-700331f1c294");

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class GuidClass
        {
            public Guid Value;
        }

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
        public static extern UInt32 PowerGetActiveScheme(
            IntPtr UserRootPowerKey,
            ref IntPtr ActivePolicyGuid
        );

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern UInt32 PowerReadACValueIndex(
            IntPtr RootPowerKey,
            ref Guid SchemeGuid,
            ref Guid SubGroupOfPowerSettingsGuid,
            ref Guid PowerSettingGuid,
            ref UInt32 AcValueIndex
        );

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern UInt32 PowerReadDCValueIndex(
            IntPtr RootPowerKey, ref Guid SchemeGuid,
            ref Guid SubGroupOfPowerSettingsGuid,
            ref Guid PowerSettingGuid,
            ref UInt32 AcValueIndex
        );

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Guid scheme = GetActiveSchemeGuid();

            bool sleepLockEnabledAC = (GetACValue(scheme, SUB_NONE, CONSOLELOCK) == 1) ? true : false;
            bool sleepLockEnabledDC = (GetDCValue(scheme, SUB_NONE, CONSOLELOCK) == 1) ? true : false;

            Console.WriteLine("Sleep lock enabled on AC : " + sleepLockEnabledAC);
            Console.WriteLine("Sleep lock enabled on DC : " + sleepLockEnabledDC);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static Guid GetActiveSchemeGuid()
        {
            IntPtr activeSchemePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            uint res = PowerGetActiveScheme(IntPtr.Zero, ref activeSchemePtr);
            GuidClass temp = new GuidClass();
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(activeSchemePtr, temp);
            Guid scheme = temp.Value;
            return scheme;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get setting for Plugged in
        /// </summary>
        static UInt32 GetACValue(Guid scheme, Guid subgroup, Guid setting)
        {
            UInt32 value = 0;
            PowerReadACValueIndex(IntPtr.Zero, ref scheme, ref subgroup, ref setting, ref value);
            return value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get setting for On battery
        /// </summary>
        static UInt32 GetDCValue(Guid scheme, Guid subgroup, Guid setting)
        {
            UInt32 value = 0;
            PowerReadDCValueIndex(IntPtr.Zero, ref scheme, ref subgroup, ref setting, ref value);
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Debug:

[image: 1]

**Sleep lock enabled on AC : True**

[image: 2]

**Sleep lock enabled on AC : False**

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. Without your solution, I have to query WMI through C++, actually it took a long time to query that setting although I used asynchronous method.

Comment: @HauBP Glad to help you.